# How to Parent jeep Rig to Character rig

Tags: rigging, armature, parent

I want to parent the rigs, so that when I move the jeep with rig the character will also move.

[image]

Check this picture:

[image]

Comment: You probably don't want to parent one to the other as that may cause problems, try moving the roots of both at the same time so the frames line up perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a "Child of" bone constraint to the root of the character, pointing to an appropriate bone of the vehicle. You can animate the influence of the constraint, to separate the two actions. After the set up of the constraint, click its "set inverse" button to build the correct location relationship.